# How to update a form field as you type in value into another field with if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to ask how to update field based on an input field and determine the equivalent of that input..

Let's say if I type 95 on input field then on the equivalent field it is 1.0

I'm using if else in the saving part but I want it to be updated when pressing keydown in the form field.

Sample code in the saving part.

```
 if($data['raw_grade'][$key]== ""){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key] == 'INC'){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "INC";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]== 'DRP'){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "DRP";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 97.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]<= 100){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "1.00";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 94.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 97.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "1.25";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 90.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 94.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "1.50";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 87.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 90.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "1.75";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 84.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 87.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "2.00";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 81.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 84.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "2.25";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 78.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 81.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "2.50";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 75.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 78.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "2.75";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 74.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 75.5){
                $data['grade'][$key] = "3.00";
            }
```

html form. Here I want to determine the value of raw_grade into grade equivalent and how pass it on using OnKeyDown or keypress without refreshing.

```
<td><input type="text" size="8" class="form-control arrow-togglable" name="raw_grade[]" id="raw_grade[]" value="{{$grade->raw_grade}}" tabindex=1></td>
 <td><input type="text" size="8" class="form-control"  name="grade[]" id="grade[]" value="{{$grade->grade}}" readonly></td>
```

here is a simple Javascript but with no keypress update on other field...

```
function myGrade(){
    var raw_grade;
    var grade = document.getElementById("stand").value;

            if(raw_grade == ""){
                grade = "";
            }elseif(raw_grade == 'INC'){
                grade'= "INC";
            }elseif(raw_grade== 'DRP'){
                grade= "DRP";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 97.5 && raw_grade<= 100){
                grade= "1.00";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 94.5 && raw_grade< 97.5){
                grade = "1.25";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 90.5 && raw_grade< 94.5){
                grade = "1.50";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 87.5 && raw_grade< 90.5){
                grade' = "1.75";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 84.5 && raw_grade< 87.5){
                grade = "2.00";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 81.5 && raw_grade< 84.5){
               grade = "2.25";
            }elseif($data['raw_grade'][$key]>= 78.5 && $data['raw_grade'][$key]< 81.5){
                grade = "2.50";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 75.5 && raw_grade< 78.5){
                grade = "2.75";
            }elseif(raw_grade>= 74.5 && raw_grade< 75.5){
                grade = "3.00";
            }

    document.getElementById("raw_grade").value = grade;
}
```

I have this script for my moving down arrow key after typing.

```
<script>
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-togglable");
    var currentIndex = 0;

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          currentIndex = (currentIndex == 0) ? elements.length - 1 : --currentIndex;
          elements[currentIndex].focus();
          break;
        case 40:
          currentIndex = ((currentIndex + 1) == elements.length) ? 0 : ++currentIndex;
          elements[currentIndex].focus();
          break;
      }
    };
</script>
```

Please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to set a value of second field based on last key pressed in the first one.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#input1");
var output = document.querySelector("#input2");

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      output.value = 'up';
      break;
    case 40:
      output.value = 'down';
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<table><tr><td>
  <input id="input1" size="8" tabindex=1>
</td><td>
  <input id="input2" size="8" readonly>
</td></tr></table>
```

Also there is no `elseif` in JS (as in your code example) - only `else if`.